# Blacks not showing up on my texture

Tags: uv, shaders

The image on the shirt has black in it however it does not show up. It is a png.
I have a fabric texture on the shirt and mixed the image and used UV Map to size and position. What am i missing?

This is the node tree
[image]

Comment: your node setup is really hard to read, so pls use file -> pack resources and provide blend file. thx.

Comment: Your _Mix Color_ node is set to _Add_. So what you are doing there is simply this, let's say the shirt's basic color is grey with a brightness of 0.3, which means the RGB values are (0.3, 0.3, 0.3), and the png has the text in light grey like (0.6, 0.6, 0.6) and the black part is of course (0, 0, 0). When you add these values together, the text will be (0.3+0.6, 0.3+0.6, 0.3+0.6) = (0.9, 0.9, 0.9) and the black parts are (0.3+0, 0.3+0, 0.3+0) = (0.3, 0.3, 0.3), which means it stays the same grey base color because x + 0 = x.

Comment: How to make it properly depends on what you want the result to be, white text on black background over a grey shirt? And how you setup the UVs and how the image texture exactly looks like, so providing the blend file with the textures and an information what it should look like is probably best here.

Comment: i believe i am too new to add files yet however you are correct. Essentially the image is white text with black background on a grey shirt. I cant seem to find any shader setups that would compliment what i am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use *Mix* Blend Mode Instead of *Add*

You're currently using the *Add* blend mode on your mix node. Think of The black parts of the image as `0.0` and the colors underneath as `X`. *Add* mode can be thought of as `X + 0.0 = X` so the black parts won't show up.

The solution is to use the *Mix* blend mode and plug the alpha of the image into the *Factor*.

[image]

Comment: Replacing the Add blend mode with MIX blend mode worked. Thanks a million Fletcher Graham!